# malware attacked host migration advice

Tags: migration, server, malware

The problem is,

I have a server account  with servage.net
It has more than 2Tb content as files. 
Bunch of folders sub folders with active developments we have done.

From 16th March 2015 we are being suspended due to malware on the content and it was real call from them. We have ftp access only at the moment. We tried to clean them manually. Downloading and cleaning uploading fresh doesnt work as the time it takes is very high and bandwith is limited out here.

Now the bad thing is my clients are waiting almost week and frustrated.

I planed to get another server store from them and move the files of customers who need immediate activation. Can download and upload in a priority basis.(No dns changes or database need to transfer if within their cluster servers)
Q1. Will this work.
Q2. What should be the best solution for this?
Q3. How to clean? Any paid services and What will be the time factor.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer with no information about the malware itself. How do you know the system was infected? Did the hosting give you the name of the malware?
if it's a virus and you have executable files, then most probably the virus attached itself to them and it's hard to clean the files. If your files are just plain text files of code, then most probably nothing bad happened to them.

As I said, can you give more info about the malware?

Comment: The server admin mailed me and suspended the account. I have checked for malware and found few. But they say there are more. So the server still down. Server is linux. Malware is a injection to spaming.